# Second ajax button not working on user profile form

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have added a custom button which has an ajax callback with the following code to the user profile form.

```
$form['validate_2'] = array(
          '#type' => 'button',
          '#value' => t('validate 2'),
          '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'example_validate',
            'wrapper' => 'validate-settings',
            'method' => 'replace'
          ),
          '#name' => 'user_validate_2',
          '#id' => 'user-validate-2',
          '#weight' => 10
        );
```

But when I click on it, it gives me ajax error in popup saying

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: 
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_profile_form_validate() in /includes/form.inc on line 1520
```

In my ajax callback I'm simply displaying the `$form_state` array. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The form's own submit button is not with ajax.

```
function example_validate($form, &$form_state) {
dsm($form_state);
}
```

Comment: in a custom module

Comment: yes in hook_form_alter in .module file

Comment: Can you add your callback function "example_validate" code to your question?

Comment: added the callback function.

Comment: I have tried the same and it is working fine for me. I don't find any such issue. You can try what @Clive have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Drupal can't find one of its core files it's nearly always because you're trying to use it in a context in which it wouldn't be automatically included.

For example when you use the user profile form normally, the menu item makes sure the file containing the form functions is included.

For your example the missing function is in user.pages.inc, so:

```
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
```

Comment: but why it is calling that function. It should call only the callback function with `$form_state` array. is it possible? I think the button validate the whole form.

Comment: That's correct - you can use [`#limit_validation_errors`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#limit_validation_errors) to control it though

Comment: In the ajax callback the `$form_state` does not contains the updated values. It has the old values.

Comment: Check the rest of your code/contrib modules in that case, that's not what should happen in normal circumstances